# Why does PyCharm not Verify Git Commits

Tags: git, github, pycharm

[image: GitHub Commits]

When using PyCharm to commit changes to my project on GitHub (ie; the Initial Commit), it just shows the default profile picture and "Landon" (my GitHub name), whereas if I manually modify any files through GitHub.com, the commit has my profile picture, GitHub username, and the "Verified" notice. The commits through PyCharm aren't counting towards my total on GitHub.

On PyCharm > Preferences > VCS > GitHub:
[image: PyCharm VCS]
I have my GitHub account linked properly (I believe?) using developer tokens.

Any help would be appreciated, it's a bit annoying and I'm not sure how to go about this. Also sorry for the wordiness of this issue, I'm not familiar with Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commits will be counted towards your profile if they are created with an email linked to your GitHub account.

On your machine : check that `git config user.email` matches your GitHub account;
set it using `git config --global user.email <my@email>`

The "verified" notice appears if your commits are signed with your PGP key : set up your PGP key locall and configure git to sign commits.

Comment: "*set up your PGP key locally*" And configure `git` to sign commits.